# GraphAPI how to add authentication contact information when user create

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create a user in azure B2C from the azure graph API.

Could anyone let me know how to add the authentication contact detail such as email (authentication email, it is required for password reset)?

I am able to create a user but I am unable to populate the authentication email progamaticaly using graph API

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102196/azure-ad-b2c-use-graph-api-to-populate-authentication-email?rq=1

Comment: How did you create AAD B2C users? Is this local account or social account?

Comment: AAD B2C local user accounts

Comment: As I known, we cannot create local accounts with AAD create new users. Usually, we create users by sign-up. Did you create it by sign-up? If you create the accounts with sign-up, you can choose what necessary attributes needs to be filled.

Comment: I can create users in AAD B2C using graph API. but I am unable to populate the authonticate email.

Comment: Hi, @Dinusha . I see. It looks like your question is duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102196/azure-ad-b2c-use-graph-api-to-populate-authentication-email?rq=1. You can refer to Saca's answer.